# What is the name for "imperfect" verification options?

Tags: authentication, identity, terminology, biometrics

Let's say users log into a system using a voice-print. Software can read the input from the microphone, compare it to the stored sample, and tell the user *"There is a `97.5%` similarity to the voice-print stored on file"*, granting access depending on how sensitive it is. Due to the imperfections in microphones, air pressure chaos, and limited accuracy vocal-folds, no matter how hard the user tries, he will **never** be able to match his voice-print stored on file with complete accuracy.

On the other hand, if your security system uses a password string, you are able to require the password to be `100.0%` correct, as it is possible for a user to perfectly replicate a password they have entered in the past.

What is the name of this type of "imperfect password", that the user **cannot** reasonably replicate with `100%` accuracy? This would include finger/palm prints, retinal scans, voice-prints, and facial recognition.

Comment: This is a **terminology** question; ignore the fact that most of the systems listed are more accurate in science fiction and on crime shows than in real life.

Comment: "biometric" or are you expanding the scope or conceptual layers?

Comment: @schroeder Broader. The biometric systems I listed were the only authenticators I could think of that are measured with inaccuracy. I'm unclear of what you mean by the second part of the sentence.

Comment: @schroeder I suppose measuring time between keystrokes would be an example of something that is measured "imperfectly", but still not considered to be biometric.

Comment: "nondeterministic" is likely the place you need to go, but I have not heard of a conceptual term to cover what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

*Probabilistic* or *statistical* authentication are probably the best fit, the alternative to *deterministic authentication*. (Though technically, there's a degree of probability involved when password hashes are used, rather than plaintext passwords, let's just ignore that for now.)

Biometric implies a probabilistic system, but the converse is not true, e.g. knowledge-based challenge response, recognition/CAPTCHA or signature/gesture systems.

There a useful PDF paper (thesis) on the topic of biometric probabilistic models here:
http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/111855/files/EPFL_TH3954.pdf

Other related terms used in this context are: non-deterministic, stochastic, biometric hash, qualitative, intra-personal variability.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on metrics such as the false acceptance rate and the false rejection rate of your authentication system, you can set a similarity percentage for which your biometric authentication is **acceptable**.

Also, I don't think you can speak of *passwords* regarding voice authentication because it relies on an **inherence factor** as you can see [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication).